# How to disable blue highlighting on form text fields in Word?

Tags: forms, ms-word, textfield

When a text form field is clicked in by the user, the field is highlighted in blue.

How can the blue highlighting be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour should disappear once you turn on the protection for the document and allow only "Filling in forms"